# why is df update slow?

Tags: disk-usage, df, qnx

When I remove large files, then use `df` to check the disk usage, often it takes a noticeable amount of time to update the disk usage percentage appropriately.

This affects several data management scripts that are removing files until the system gets down to a specific percent of disk utilization.

I know it's easy to just throw a `sleep` in there, but I prefer to understand why the update takes a while.

So my questions are:

1. Why does `df` take some time to update?
2. Is there a better way to check disk utilization immediately after removing files (`fvstat` or something like it)?
3. Any recommendations on how to manage this data better (it's a lot of data, stacking up pretty quick...)?

I'll be satisfied with an answer for any of the above questions.

```
System: QNX Neutrino 6.4.1, PDKSH
Commands: `rm -rf bigdatafiles*.tar` and `df -kP`
```

Comment: What filesystem are you using?  btrfs?

Comment: @psusi Good question. The file system is QNX6.

Comment: How exactly are you removing the files (not just the commands but also how they are chained)? Is there a chance that another process may have the files open when you remove them?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, there is a remote chance they might be open, and it does happen when none are open. The logger might be writing to one. The script uses `find` to dump all the file names that match the criteria to a file, then removes each with `rm -fv 'cat $FILELIST'`. They files are independent, large binary data files, though some small text logs are also removed this way. Normally, I don't see the effect unless it's a large file (bigger than 5 meg). Does this address the question of "how are they chained?" (Note that the backticks were removed, so I put single quotes as placemarks.)

Comment: With a normal unix, the only reason the disk space wouldn't appear as free as soon as `rm` returns is that open files are not actually deleted until they are closed. It's possible that QNX is doing something unusual.

Comment: Maybe you have a NFS mount which is not available actually?

Comment: @RichardGomes That's a good thought. I'll go back and look at that system and see.